# Deserialize(convert) a JsonObject to DateTime without POJO

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have the following jsonObject:

```
"dateCreated": {
        "year": 2021,
        "dayOfYear": 145,
        "equalNow": false,
        "weekyear": 2021,
        "chronology": {
          "zone": {
            "ID": "UTC"
          }
        },
        "weekOfWeekyear": 21,
        "secondOfMinute": 10,
        "millisOfDay": 10990000,
        "monthOfYear": 5,
        "dayOfWeek": 2,
        "beforeNow": true,
        "minuteOfDay": 183,
        "dayOfMonth": 25,
        "era": 1,
        "zone": {
          "ID": "UTC"
        },
        "yearOfCentury": 21,
        "centuryOfEra": 20,
        "hourOfDay": 3,
        "secondOfDay": 10990,
        "millis": 1621911790000,
        "yearOfEra": 2021,
        "minuteOfHour": 3,
        "millisOfSecond": 0,
        "afterNow": false
      }
```

I need to convert it for this format:

```
2021-05-25T03:03:10.000Z
```

Since I don't have a pojo for that object, it's coming from a jsonArray, I'm struggling to get a Datetime from it.
I tried ObjectMapper, JSON(GSON) and still no success.

Does anyone have a clue how can I do it?

edit.: It's a list of Recordings that I converted to JsonArray (to manipulate, adding another field into the json). When I convert the list to jsonArray, that field (type DateTime) becomes serialized and I need it back to the correct format to pass it forward.

```
Recording.class;
private final DateTime dateCreated;
List<Recording> listRecordings;

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(listRecordings);
 
jsonArray ->
[
{
  
  "offset": 179161383840,

  "type": "AUDIO",
 
  "duration": 232,
  "codec": "OPUS",
  "dateCreated": {
    "year": 2021,
    "dayOfYear": 145,
    "equalNow": false,
    "weekyear": 2021,
    "chronology": {
      "zone": {
        "ID": "UTC"
      }
    },
    "weekOfWeekyear": 21,
    "secondOfMinute": 10,
    "millisOfDay": 10990000,
    "monthOfYear": 5,
    "dayOfWeek": 2,
    "beforeNow": true,
    "minuteOfDay": 183,
    "dayOfMonth": 25,
    "era": 1,
    "zone": {
      "ID": "UTC"
    },
    "yearOfCentury": 21,
    "centuryOfEra": 20,
    "hourOfDay": 3,
    "secondOfDay": 10990,
    "millis": 1621911790000,
    "yearOfEra": 2021,
    "minuteOfHour": 3,
    "millisOfSecond": 0,
    "afterNow": false
  },
  "size": 521517,

  "containerFormat": "MKA",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}
]
```

I need to revert back dateCreated for the original format: 2021-05-25T03:03:10.000Z

Edit3.:

My workaround:

```
 for (Recording recording : listRecordings) {

    Object jsonObject = JSONObject.wrap(recording);
    ((JSONObject) jsonObject).put("dateCreated", recording.getDateCreated());
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

}
```

Best Regards,

Comment: U can try this post: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persist-json-object. I did and success

Comment: Where are you getting that JSON? It appears that someone has incorrectly configured Jackson in the application that is writing it by failing to include the module for Java 8 time.

Comment: It's a Twilio response from its records.